# Is there a way to get a demo of your competitive match, with the voice chat?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I need a demo of a competitive match from CS:GO with the voice chat (what people said). Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: What do you need this for?  Giving us some context would make this much more useful.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [here](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?l=german&id=297072017), it says:

1. Have your developer console enabled
2. Open it
3. Type this, it makes sure your own voice is part of the game sound

   > voice_loopback 1
4. Start a game
5. Open the console and type

   > record yourDemoName
6. When you are finished, exit to menu or type "stop"
7. If you want to play the demo, type

   > playdemo yourDemoName

I wasn't able to check it out so far, but I will do it later today.
One thing is sure, you can't get old demos to have voice enabled, sadly.